# Approximately or about?

Tags: word-choice

Which sentence is more clear? I want to say that sales increased by three times. But it is not exactly three times, it was an increase from 15 to 47.

> 1. As for selling fair-trade bananas, Switzerland, which occupied the
>    highest position in both estimated years, witnessed **about** a
>    three-times increase from 15 to 47 million euros.
> 2. As for selling fair-trade bananas, Switzerland, which occupied the
>    highest position in both estimated years, witnessed **approximately** a
>    three-times increase from 15 to 47 million euros.

Comment: _Approximately_ is much more suitable in this kind of formal sentence.

Comment: But *a three-times increase* is not idiomatic: we say "a three-**fold** increase".

Comment: There's a bit of a "registry mismatch" here - the use of ***witnessed** [an increase]* reflects "vivid, creative, attention-grabbing" writing style (even more "poetic" than ***saw***, which is also *metaphorical*), but ***approximately*** is a "dry, technical, formal, academic" usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words "about" and "approximately" both serve the same purpose in this sentence, but "approximately" is slightly better, for a few reasons (one of those reasons being that "about" can mean far more other things which you don't intend here).

Also, there is a [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/306072/approximately-or-about#comment572723_306072) saying that you should say "three-fold" instead of "three-times", but if we're heading in that direction, I'll take it one step further and say that a better way to word this would be to say "an increase **by a factor of** three" instead of "three-fold" or "three-times" which are slightly more awkward. This would work with the word "approximately" in both of the following ways: "an increase by approximately a factor of three" and "an increase by a factor of approximately three".